# Trigger en SQL para enviar email

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Necesito crear un `trigger` en una tabla de SQL para enviar un correo electrónico si el registro insertado cumple unas condiciones.

Es decir, creo el `trigger` en la `Tabla1` para enviar un email a X si en el registro insertado el `IdCircuito= 53`, el `IdTipoDoc = 45` y el `Gestor = 'Gest1'`. Además, en el cuerpo del mensaje del correo quiero que aparezca el valor de un determinado campo de ese registro insertado.

Yo he hecho algo así pero el `trigger` se ejecuta siempre independientemente del registro insertado:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.SendEmail   
   ON  dbo.TitulosDoc 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 

BEGIN        
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TitulosDoc WHERE IdCircuito = 53 AND IdTipoDoc = 45 AND Gestor = 'Gest1')
BEGIN
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
      @recipients = 'rsg@gmail.com', 
      @subject = 'Requerimiento generado', 
      @body = 'Se ha generado un nuevo requerimiento: ';
END
END
GO
```

En el *body* es donde quiero que se muestre el texto con el valor del campo del registro insertado:

```
@body = 'Se ha generado un nuevo requerimiento: ' + TitulosDoc.NombreDocumento;
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: ¿Qué manejador de base de datos utilizas?

Comment: El Management Studio de SQL Server

Comment: ¿Qué versión usas actualmente de Management Studio?

Comment: La 10.0.5500 con el SQL Server 2008

Comment: Hola Rsg. Toma en cuenta que los triggers se ejecutan una vez por sentencia y no por registro. De modo que si insertas varios registros a la vez con una sentencia (ejemplos: `insert into ... select * from ...` o `insert into tbl values (...), (...), (...)`), el trigger ejecuta una sola vez. ¿Qué quieres hacer en ese caso?

Comment: Hola sstan. En esta tabla solo se insertará un registro cada cierto tiempo, por tanto, ya me sirve el trigger por sentencia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La clave está en usar la tabla temporal especial `inserted` que contiene el registro que se acaba de insertar:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.SendEmail   
   ON  dbo.TitulosDoc 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN        
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  declare @body nvarchar(max);
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE IdCircuito = 53 AND IdTipoDoc = 45 AND Gestor = 'Gest1')
  BEGIN
    set @body = 'Se ha generado un nuevo requerimiento: ' + (select NombreDocumento from inserted);
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
      @recipients = 'rsg@gmail.com', 
      @subject = 'Requerimiento generado', 
      @body = @body;
  END
END
GO
```

Pero solo para que quede claro, este trigger solo puede manejar sentencias `INSERT` que inserten un registro a la vez solamente. En teoría, un trigger escrito correctamente debería poder manejar sentencias `INSERT` que resulten en varios registros insertados (o hasta ningún registro insertado). Pero como mencionastes en los comentarios que eso definitivamente no es tu caso, este trigger debería ser suficiente para tu necesidad.

Comment: Gracias por tu propuesta pero me da un error al concatenar el texto literal del body con la variable @nombreDocumento. Me lanza un error de: "sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '+'" al comprobar la sintaxis de la sentencia. ¿Sabes que puede ser? Muchas gracias otra vez.

Comment: En efecto, disculpa. Un error de mi parte. Hice el ajuste.

Comment: Grande!!! Perfecto, @sstan. Tu respuesta me ha funcionado y se ejecuta de maravilla. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.